# What does getActivity() mean?

Tags: android

What does `getActivity()` mean? I saw in somewhere, they wrote `MainActivity.this.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback)` instead of `getActivity()`. could someone explain what this two lines mean?

```
  someView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        // Called when the user long-clicks on someView
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }

            // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
            mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            view.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Most likely `getActivity()` is a user-defined method not from the Android API. Can you post more code? In particular, I would like to know if this is in a class which extends Activty or something else.

Comment: When you use fragments it is only way to get context

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Two likely definitions:

- `getActivity()` in a `Fragment` returns the `Activity` the `Fragment` is currently associated with. (see [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29)).
- `getActivity()` is user-defined.

Comment: thanks! and could you explain what does this line mean  **MainActivity.this ** ?

Comment: for your code in `MainActivity`, `MainActivity.this` will return an Activity object for the instance of `MainActivity` you are in.  `Activity` extends `Context` so this is often used to obtain or pass around a `Context`

Answer (score 11):

`getActivity()` is used for `fragment`. For `activity`, wherever you can use `this`, you can replace the `this` in `fragment` in similar cases with `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 3):

getActivity()- Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

Answer (score 0):

I to had a similar doubt what I got to know was `getActivity()` returns the  `Activity` to which the fragment is associated.

The `getActivity()` method is used generally in static fragment as the associated activity will not be static and non static member cannot be used in static member.

[image: I used <code>getActivity()</code> here to get non-static activity to which the the placeholder fragment is associated.]