# Unknown method getIntent

Tags: android

I am making an application on AIDE for android, and I'm using an intent to send data from an activity to a normal class.I'm using:

```
int level= (currentLevel*100)/scale;
Intent i = new Intent(context, caller.class);
i.putExtra("level",level);
context.startActivity(i);
```

in the class that sends the data ("percentage.class").

```
int p = getIntent().getIntExtra("level");
```

in the class that receives the data ("caller.class")
which gives me an error: "Unknown method getIntent()".
What can I do to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your class extend Activity? Because getIntent() is a method in the Activity class.

Comment: You say that "I'm using an intent to send data from an activity to a normal class". You can't do that. A normal class cannot be 'started' like an Activity is, an instance of it has to be instantiated. You can pass data to it via the constructor when you do so or afterwards by accessing its public fields. Add more detail and context to your question so we can better understand your requirements.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to receive information through an intent in a class that extends appWidgetProvider?

Comment: Activity.Intent, did not work

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to say in your question what is the problem. The class in which you are calling `getIntent` does not inherit the class Activity.

Unlike what other people are saying inheriting Activity is unlikely to give you what you're looking for. What I'm suspecting is that you're calling getIntent in a button or something like this. Since it might be wrapped inside a method that isn't directly pointing to your activity. You should "keep" a pointer to the activity.

Usually, what you are looking for should be in the context. Calling `context.getIntent` might work if your context is the thing I "believe" it should be. Show more to give us a better idea of what is going on. Because since getIntent is calling from the activity. `getIntent` is the same as writing `this.getIntent` but Java implicitely calls function on `this` and then on the global scope (the thing you import).

If you want to avoid this problem, alway call it from `this` and when you're calling from within a Handler, you can keep references in your class to the current activity. I'm not so sure but on some object, you should have a function `getActivity` that will return the activity in which they are located.

you could have something like this. `obj.getActivity().getIntent()...`

Check this out: [What does getActivity() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610995/what-does-getactivity-mean)

Comment: What I want to do is use the class that extends activity in a class that extends an appWidgetProvider. But I don't know how to do this, so I thought that maybe I could use a class just to make the transition and call the variable from the normal class.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to use an intent to send data to a class that extends appWidgetProvider?

Answer (score 0):

The `getIntent()` method belongs to the `Activity` class. You will get this error if your class does not extend `Activity`. Try extending `Activity` and see if it works.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call a method from an activity in an appwidgetprovider?

Comment: @user1905507 try Activity.getIntent(); I'm not too sure sorry :(