# how to launch an activity from a fragment of a navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I built a navigation drawer. When the app launches, I direct the user directly to "MainMenuActivity" activity from the MainActivity. 
Inside the "MainMenuActivity", there is a button that should direct the user to another activity which is "Order List"; I applied two code parts but non is working:

The first code:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainmenu, container, false);

    Button Orderlistbtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.orderlistbtn);
    Orderlistbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, OrderList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

the app doesn't run, the first code gives me the following error in the logcat:

```
  Error:(41, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(MainMenuActivity,Class<OrderList>)
   constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; MainMenuActivity cannot be converted to String)
   constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; MainMenuActivity cannot be converted to Context)
```

The second code:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainmenu, container, false);

    Button Orderlistbtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.orderlistbtn);
    Orderlistbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OrderList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

but the app crashes once it launches with the following logcat error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{package/package.MainMenuActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: package.MainMenuActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

this is "activity_mainmenu.xml" file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@android:color/background_light">


<Button
    android:background="#ffff8800"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="          My order list        "
    android:id="@+id/orderlistbtn"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of `MainMenuActivity.this`

Comment: @Aloweiwi SHOW YOUR XML `activity_mainmenu`

Comment: `MainMenuActivity` is not an `Activity`, but somewhere you're treating it as such. If by "I direct the user directly to 'MainMenuActivity' activity from the MainActivity.", you mean you're calling `startActivity()` with an `Intent` targeting `MainMenuActivity`, then that's your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**[getActivity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610995/what-does-getactivity-mean)** in a Fragment returns the Activity the Fragment is currently associated with .

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OrderList.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit**

Secondly, You are getting **[ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)**

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance.

Comment: @Aloweiwi please post your `xml`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to call next activity, Hope this will solve your problem

```
Intent intent = new Intent((ParentActivity)getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
(ParentActivity)getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```