# Is invoking getActivity() necessary for invoking getLayoutInflater()?

Tags: java, android

I found two people with different way to invoke `inflate()`. One invokes without calling `getActivity()` but the other one invokes with `getActivity()`. For example, see the following snippet. Is it necessary? And is there any difference?

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View dialogView = //getActivity()
             getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_note, null);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, read this [What does getActivity() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610995/what-does-getactivity-mean) . I'm not sure exactly in what context you are asking your question, apparently we are talking about working in a fragment. getActivity is used so that you can access the activity to which it is attached from the fragment. If you are in a fragment, then when you call getActivity, you will get the layoutInflater of your activity and will work with it. If you just call layoutInflater, then you will refer to the LayoutInflater of your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you are using **getLayoutInflater()** inside a Fragment the **getActivity()** would be needed as fragment dosent has its own context and if you are invoking in An Activity then it wont require **getActivity()** as android assumes cureent context which is **this** so you can write

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View dialogView = this.
         getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_note, null);}
```

as getLayoutinflater() is present in Activity Context